# TListView Item Detail Font to Monospace

Tags: listview, fonts, firemonkey, c++builder

am trying to set a monospace font on my Androaid application using one of the default fonts but it didn't work. I tried "Courier New" or "Consolas" but none of the worked out. It seems UI doesn't respond me at all regarding to the fonts but size.

```
TListViewItem* item2;
while(!myQuery->Eof)
{
   item2 = ListView2->Items->Add();

   item2->Objects->DetailObject->Font->Family = "Courier New";
   item2->Objects->DetailObject->Font->Style = TFontStyles()<< fsBold;
   item2->Objects->DetailObject->Font->Size =13;

   item2->Text      = myQuery->FieldByName("Description")->AsString.Trim();
   item2->Detail    = " | "+Format("%-5s", OPENARRAY(TVarRec,(myQuery->FieldByName("Unit")->AsString)))+" | "+Format("%7s", OPENARRAY(TVarRec,(myQuery->FieldByName("Qty")->AsString)))+" |   "+CurrToStrF(myQuery->FieldByName("Price")->AsCurrency,ffFixed,2)+" | "+Format("%3s", OPENARRAY(TVarRec,(myQuery->FieldByName("Dsc")->AsString)))+"%|"+Format("%4s", OPENARRAY(TVarRec,(CurrToStrF(myQuery->FieldByName("Vat")->AsCurrency,ffFixed,1))))+"%|"+Format("%-20s", OPENARRAY(TVarRec,(myQuery->FieldByName("Notes")->AsString)))+"|";
   myQuery->Next();
}
```

Comment: There are specific tags for C++Builder here. Please use them instead of separate tags for C++ and Builder, so that your question will be correctly identified. You also don't need to repeat the tag information in the title; it's clutter, because the tags already contain that information. It might help if you added a tag for the specific version of C++Builder you're using, as FMX changes frequently (and sometimes drastically) between versions.

Answer (score 0):

I use monospaced texts in VCL all the time. The problem is that only few fonts are capable of it. Try this:

```
mm_log->Font->Charset=OEM_CHARSET;
mm_log->Font->Name="System";
mm_log->Font->Pitch=fpFixed;
```

where `mm_log` is your component you want to be mono spaced (in my case it was a `TMemo`)...

However I do not use FMX and non Win32 IDE/Aps so with different environment the situation might be different.